# Why $y=2\tan^{-1}\left(\cos(x)+\sin(x)\right)$ solves $\cos(y)+ \sin(y)(\cos(x)+\sin(x))=1$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I tried to find those points on the sphere, where

$$\cos(y)+ \sin(y)\cos(x)+\sin(y)\sin(x)=1.\tag{1}$$

$y=2\pi n$ is trivial but after some fruitless attempts I gave up and I asked [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/lkjash5). He gave me:
$$y=2\tan^{-1}\left(\cos(x)+\sin(x)\right)\tag{2}$$

For this solution Wolfram also demands for
$$
\cos^2(x)+ \sin^2(x) + 2\cos(x)\sin(x) +1 \neq 0
$$
which at least to me seems a little confusing, since it's always true: $x$ is real.

How to get $(2)$ from $(1)$?

Comment: I guess some code at Wolfram allowed for complex arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{1-\cos y}{\sin y} = \frac{2\sin^2 \frac{y}{2}}{2\sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{y}{2}} = \tan \frac{y}{2}.$$